# Is there a way to register user and password for an account on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a Web Service running on IIS.
My goal is to be able to access a network folder on a Linux machine (Samba Server) which is password protected. Can I make a user account on IIS which will have username and password register and this account will be the account the asp.net uses to run the service. Also I will give full access to this account from the Linux machine.

My Question is, if it is possible to pass a password to IIS metabase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I do this with impersonation in code. You could use [this small helper class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx) in an easy-to-use manner:

```
using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" ) )
{
   // <code that executes under the new context>
}
```

Alternatively, there is also [ASP.NET Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) available.

Answer (score 1):

[How TO: Change Application Pool Identity Programmatically](http://How%20TO%3a%20Change%20Application%20Pool%20Identity%20Programmatically)

```
   //Initialize the metabase path
    string metabasePath = "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools";
    //Specify the name for your application pool
    string appPoolName = "testAppPool"; //specify the domain account as domain\username
    //Specify the identity that will run the application pool
    string appPoolUser = "User1";
    //Specify the password for the user
    string appPoolPass = "Password1";
    DirectoryEntry pool1;
    DirectoryEntry apppools = new DirectoryEntry(metabasePath);
    pool1 = apppools.Children.Find(appPoolName, "IIsApplicationPool");

    /*Change Application Pool Identity*/
    pool1.InvokeSet("AppPoolIdentityType", new Object[] { 3 });
    pool1.InvokeSet("WAMUserName", new Object[] { Environment.MachineName + @"\" + appPoolUser }); //If you are using a local account

    pool1.InvokeSet("WAMUserPass", new Object[] { appPoolPass });  
    /*Commit changes*/

    pool1.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Hello again... My problem that the main.asmx.cs doesnt recognise the  DirectoryEntry method.... and I cant get to add a reference on System.DirectoryServices.... Any ideas how to overcome this???